# How to get the closest value in a list?

Tags: python, list, math

I have a variable which looks like this: `my_value = 188` and I have a list which looks like this:

```
my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '190,00', '0,15'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,38', '0,44'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,94', '0,60'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,49', '0,78'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '187,99', '0,101'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,76', '0,10'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,16', '0,20'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,56', '0,35'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,01', '0,40'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '188,13', '0,75'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '187,95', '0,85'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,20', '0,11'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,10', '0,31'], 
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '189,32', '0,45'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,61', '0,67'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,01', '0,72'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '187,36', '0,80']]
```

As you can see in `my_list` the numbers in index `[2]` are descending while the numbers in index `[3]` are ascending. Now for every list I want to check at what index `[3]` is index `[2]` the closest to `my_value` BUT it should not fall below my_value.

I tried below code:

```
for key,sublists in itertools.groupby(my_list,lambda y:y[0]):
        v=[] #initialize it in case no element fulfill the condition
        for v in itertools.takewhile(lambda x:float(x[-1].replace(",","."))<my_value ,sublists):
            pass
        if v: 
            print(v[-1])
```

I received the following output:

```
0,101
0,85
0,80
```

The output I want is:

```
0,78
0,75
0,72
```

Comment: What do you mean by "surpass your value"? In your example desired output, the values at index 2 are all greater than 188 and therefore suprass your value. Do you mean they shouldn't go below your value?

Comment: @sunnytown with surpassing I mean `<188`. Its the other way around. I have to change my vocuabluary. Instead of surpassing I mean 'falling below'. You understand?

Comment: I do, I just wanted to clarify if this is indeed what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of work where `pandas` comes to the rescue:

```
import pandas as pd
my_value = 188
my_list = [] # complete this with your list above

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list) # make a DataFrame out of your list
df[2] = df[2].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float) # convert those strings to actual floats
df[3] = df[3].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)
selected = df[df[2]>my_value].groupby(by=0).agg({2:'min',3:'last'}) # selects what you want

print(list(selected[3])) # if you just want those values
```

will output

> [0.72, 0.78, 0.75]

`selected` will look like:

```
0       2       3
Italy   188.01  0.72
Morocco 188.49  0.78
Spain   188.13  0.75
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_value = 188
numbers = [float(line[2].replace(',', '.')) for line in my_list]
minima = [(num - my_value, line[3]) for num, line in zip(numbers, my_list) if num >= my_value]
minima = sorted(minima, key=lambda x: x[0])
top3 = [val[1] for val in minima[:3]]
print(top3)
```

First I create a list `numbers` which holds the values of index 2 of each list in `my_list` converted to a float, so we are actually able to perform calculations on these numbers. This is done using a list comprehension.

Then I create a new list `minima` where I calculate the difference between `my_value` and all values in `numbers`, with the condition that the value in numbers has to be greater than or equal to `my_number`. By using `zip(number, my_list)` I simultaneously loop of both the list `numbers` and `my_list` so that I can put together the differense `num - myvalue` together with the respective value in index 3 of `my_list` into a tuple.

The list `minima` then looks like this:

```
[(2.0, '0,15'),
 (1.9000000000000057, '0,32'),
 (1.3799999999999955, '0,44'),
 (0.9399999999999977, '0,60'),
 (0.4900000000000091, '0,78'),
 (2.759999999999991, '0,10'),
 (2.1599999999999966, '0,20'),
 (1.5600000000000023, '0,35'),
 (1.009999999999991, '0,40'),
 (0.12999999999999545, '0,75'),
 (2.1999999999999886, '0,11'),
 (2.0999999999999943, '0,31'),
 (1.3199999999999932, '0,45'),
 (0.6100000000000136, '0,67'),
 (0.009999999999990905, '0,72')]
```

Then I sort that list in ascending order by its first value in the tuple which is the difference between `my_value` and the numbers in index 3. I then take the first three and return just the second value in the tuple.

Just on a sidenote: If you are dealing with tabular data like this, it might be a good idea to look into the pandas library. Another answer on this post shows a way to do this with pandas. It can often be easier and more user friendly to deal with tabular data with that library because it offers alot of functionality to easily perform alot of data manipulation and analysis.

Comment: Your `top3` is giving the correct output. Can you give a detailed explantion of what you actually did?

Comment: I have edited my post with an explanation.

Comment: @TangerCity Are you sure this gives the correct resuilt? It seems to only coincidently give the right output because the values happen to be in a similar range for each country.

Comment: Oh I might have actually misunderstood the question. It is probably true that this will not always give the correct output, since I don't group by countries. Sorry for that.

Comment: @sunnytown How do you add that grouping by countries?

Comment: @TangerCity Another possible issue: what should happen if **no** values are greater than `my_value` for a given country?

Comment: @ekhumoro thats impossible, all the data should cross 188.

Comment: @TangerCity In that case, your original code can be fixed in a very simple way. Replace the body of the for-loop with this: `v = sorted(x for x in sublists if float(x[2].replace(',', '.')) >= my_value)[0]; print(v[-1])`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have 2 for loops. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @TangerCity Like this: `for key,sublists in itertools.groupby(my_list,lambda y:y[0]): v = min(x for x in sublists if float(x[2].replace(',', '.')) >= my_value); print(v[-1])`. So, for each country, take all the values equal to or greater than `my_value`, and then select the minimum.

Comment: @ekhumoro that is a good one to. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the built-in sort()?:

```
my_list = [row for row in my_list if float(row[2].replace(',','.')) >= my_value]
my_list.sort(key=lambda l:float(l[2].replace(',','.')))

for row in my_list:
    print(row)
```

>

```
['Italy', 'Meat', '188,01', '0,72']
['Spain', 'Meat', '188,13', '0,75']
['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,49', '0,78']
['Italy', 'Meat', '188,61', '0,67']
['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,94', '0,60']
['Spain', 'Meat', '189,01', '0,40']
['Italy', 'Meat', '189,32', '0,45']
['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,38', '0,44']
['Spain', 'Meat', '189,56', '0,35']
['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32']
['Morocco', 'Meat', '190,00', '0,15']
['Italy', 'Meat', '190,10', '0,31']
['Spain', 'Meat', '190,16', '0,20']
['Italy', 'Meat', '190,20', '0,11']
['Spain', 'Meat', '190,76', '0,10']
```